# Why is event.namespace undefined for click event?

Tags: jquery

Given this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn").on("click.mynamespace", function (e) {
    $("#result").text("namespace: " + e.namespace);
});
```

Why is namespace always undefined?

EDit:

What I want to be able to do is connect multiple instances of an event handler to a button's click event. Then, when the button is clicked, each instance is called, in turn. Each instance of the event handler then needs to disconnect itself, so that if the button is clicked again, that handler instance is not called.

Comment: The real question is: why is the event listener called if the namespace doesn't match mynamespace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `namespace` property is only defined if the event was triggered using jQuery's `.trigger` or `.triggerHandler` methods. Otherwise, how would jQuery know which namespace to use if there were multiple?

http://jsfiddle.net/GYyef/2/

http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

If your goal is to have the event only happen once, the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method would be more appropriate.

Comment: oh, i'd hoped that all handlers would be called for the click event, and in each handler i would be able to retrieve the namespace in order to disconnect the event handler.

Comment: @slippyr4 the event data mentioned by karim79 would be the way to do that, however, if you only want the event to happen once, the `.one` method would be more appropriate.

Comment: post that as an answer, it's exactly what i wanted!